# Вход в систему в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте. У меня есть одна страница для входа в систему. Хочу что бы оно сначала показывалась а когда пользователь войдет в систему открылась другая. Что бы в файле main.php я поставил ту страницу которая показивается после входа в систему

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере `Site` в `actionIndex` прописываете

```
return $this->render("название нужного вида")
```

Откроется ваш вид для входа в систему.
Прописываете в любом контроллере скрипт для входа в систему и в самом конце

```
$this->redirect("Ссылка")
```

Если я, конечно, правильно понял вопрос

Comment: только не `"Название вида, куда нужно перенаправить пользователя"`, в redirect передаётся ссылка

Comment: @Blacknife, какая ссылка?

Comment: @slo_nik url, указатель ресурса, принимает строку либо массив, который прогоняется затем через Url::to()

Comment: причём нужно редирект возвращать `return $this->redirect("Ссылка")`

Comment: @Blacknife, я бы не назвал имя контроллера и вида, куда надо перевести пользователя ссылкой

Comment: У меня редирект работает и без return

Comment: @slo_nik это совсем необязательно только имя контроллера и вида, это любой URL который будет конвертирован в абосолютную ссылку, хоть ссылка на файл

Comment: @Андрей работает, но за такую неочевидность в коде по рукам бьют)

Comment: @Blacknife, да, конвертирует, но это не видно))) А видно только имя контроллера/действия. И эта строка уж никак не похожа на ссылку.)))

Comment: @slo_nikда ну именно потому что это не только контроллер/действие это и называется ссылкой, даже в доках)